# MVC6 Facebook integration and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a new app using mvc6 and web api, using Angular as consumer.

I tried to integrate Facebook login by including

```
 "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta6"
```

configuring it, and calling during this post action:

```
[Route("api/externallogin")]
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
}
```

Now, every time I click the button raising the method above, I get this message on browsers (firefox or chrome equally):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog[...]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:65167' is therefore not allowed access.
```

(note: the above snippet was take on chrome. Firefox catch the same error, with different words)

I cannot find any solution for this. Can Anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: did you see the documentation? http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/sociallogins.html

Comment: @JoeAudette, yep I rtfm. That documentation is related to MVC, I'm actually using web.api to manage the requests.
I even tried to create a new project as suggested by the article, and it works like a charm. So, probably something related to how web.api handle requests.

Comment: much of what is documented would still be required, ie configuring the middleware, setting up the application at facebook, adding the clientid and app secret in configure services. none of which have you mentioned doing in your question. to me the error looks like you have not setup the app at facebook and therefore facebook is rejecting the requests from an unknown url

Comment: @JoeAudette, I didn't mentioned the facebook configuration because it was supposed to be done.
Still, I think it's a problem of how web api handles the request: the fact that creating a dummy project with standard ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates (the one that come with visual studio 2015) works perfectly. Even catching the url, copying on the browser works without a problem, raising ExternalLoginCallback correctly.